# how to pad spaces to the right using %s in python?

Tags: python

in my program I have to organize stings to be of a certain length, in this case I set the max length to a. when I set it up the way I written below, I get an error in the python visualizer that I am using a unsupported format character. I can't use format or ljust to format my answer.

```
a =9
string = '%(a)s' % 'k'
print (string + 'KITE')
```

the problem is I know this will work if the variable a was a number, so what is going on?

edit- the desired out put would be  `'        kKITE'`

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
If `rjust` is not allowed either:

```
>>> s = '%s' % (' '*8 + 'k')
>>> s + 'KITE'
'        kKITE'
```

I believe you are looking for `rjust`:

```
>>> 'kKITE'.rjust(9)
'      kKITE'
```

Or for your example:

```
>>> s = ('%s' % 'k').rjust(8)
>>> s + 'KITE'
'       kKITE'
```

Comment: OP: "I can't use format or ljust to format my answer." Presumably this includes rjust, but I've no idea.

Comment: @jhpratt this uses `rjust` Do they mean both?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 9
string = "%s" %('k' * a)
print (string + 'KITE')

  >> 'kkkkkkkkkKITE'


a = 9
string = "%s%s" %(' ' * a, 'k')
print (string + 'KITE')

  >> '         kKITE'
```

Comment: i have edited my answer to account for the posters edit :)